# Regex for lines containing an odd number of pipe characters

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I'm cleaning up a LaTeX file, and I'm in a situation where I need to distinguish absolute value |x| from the set "such that" symbol i.e. {x | x < 0}.

The first step for me is to find all lines containing an odd number of | characters (i.e. the pipe symbol).

In principle, I know how to do this, but I've tried the following regex command with no luck.

```
egrep '^[^\|]*\|([^\|]*\|[^\|]*\|)*[^\|]*$'
```

The idea is that a matching line contains, in order:

- The line start
- 0 or more non-pipe characters
- Exactly one pipe character
- 0 or more copies of text containing exactly 2 pipes
- The line end

However, for some reason this isn't working.
I run the command on the following file:

```
\[
S = \{ x | x < 0}
y = |x|
\]
```

and none of the lines match.

I suspect I'm making a silly mistake somewhere, possibly to do with escaping the pipe characters,
but I'm stumped as to what's wrong.

Can anybody tell me either how to fix this, or provide an alternate expression which matches lines containing an odd number of pipe characters?

Comment: `gsub()` a pair of pipes then see if there is one left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `[]`, `|` is not a special character so should not be escaped by `\`.  Try:

```
egrep '^[^|]*\|([^|]*\|[^|]*\|)*[^|]*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use awk for this purpose:

```
awk -F '|' '!(NF%2)'
```

**TESTING:**

```
echo "a|bc|d|erg" | awk -F '|' '!(NF%2)'
```

OUTPUT:

```
a|bc|d|erg

echo "abc|d|ergxy" | awk -F '|' '!(NF%2)'
```

OUTPUT:

Comment: I think you have it backwards.  This matches only lines with an even number of pipes.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF&&(NF-1)%2' file
```

example:

```
kent$  cat file
|foo|bar
| | | | |
||||||
|||||||

kent$  awk -F'|' 'NF&&(NF-1)%2' file
| | | | |
|||||||
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl, which is cross platform (Windows too) and generally installed everywhere these days, is my axe of choice:

perl -ne 'print if (s/\|/\|/g) %2 == 1' file

Comment: `print if y/|// % 2` is more idiomatic and probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

#### script.sed

```perl
#!/bin/sed -nf

# Save to hold
h

# Delete all non | chars
s@[^|]@@g

# Odd match
/^\(||\)*|$/ {
  # Fetch hold
  g
  s@^@odd\t:@
}

# Even match
/^\(||\)\+$/ {
  # Fetch hold
  g
  s@^@even\t:@
}

# No match
/^$/ {
  # Fetch hold
  g
  s@^@none\t:@
}

# Print
p
```

#### data.txt

```
do|odd
do|odd|match|me
|even match|me
do|even match|me
do|even match|also|me|please

no-match
```

#### shell

```sh
sed -nf script.sed data.txt
```

#### stdout

```
odd :do|odd
odd :do|odd|match|me
even    :|even match|me
even    :do|even match|me
even    :do|even match|also|me|please
none    :
none    :no-match
```